# MVC 4 CONTROLLER

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I'm trying to make a double view state here, first Im making a bool that checks if the user is authenticated then If it is it sends me to a view, if im not it sends me to another view.
Problem is that I get this error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult', but this dictionary requires a model item
>   of type TheNonViolenceProject.Models.ViewModels.PageViewModel`1[TheNonViolenceProject.Models.Pages.EducationPage]'.

Here is my code:

```
public class EducationPageController : PageController<EducationPage> {
    private bool isUserLoggedin = true;

    public ActionResult Index(EducationPage currentPage) {
        PageViewModel<EducationPage> model = PageViewModel.Create(currentPage);
        if (isUserLoggedin) {
            return View(IndexIsAuthenticated(currentPage));
        }
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult IndexIsAuthenticated(EducationPage currentPage {
        //isUserLoggedin = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        PageViewModel<EducationPage> modelIsAuthenticated = PageViewModel.Create(currentPage);
        return View(modelIsAuthenticated);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
    PageViewModel<EducationPage> model = PageViewModel.Create(currentPage);
    if (isUserLoggedin)
    {
        return View(IndexIsAuthenticated(currentPage));
    }
```

to

```
    PageViewModel<EducationPage> model = PageViewModel.Create(currentPage);
    if (isUserLoggedin)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("IndexIsAuthenticated", model);
    }
```

Comment: Hm, Trying debugg this but I get null now. Somehow it dsnt goes in to my IndexIsAuthenticated with ur code :/

Answer (score 0):

I guess this line

```
return View(IndexIsAuthenticated(currentPage));
```

should be

```
return IndexIsAuthenticated(currentPage);
```